# Java Jersey Access Filter From Different Package

Tags: java, jersey

I follow this [tutorial](http://arnavawasthi.blogspot.kr/2011/09/writing-custom-filter-for-jersey.html) on building a filter for Jersey 1.x. It works fine if the filter Class (i.e. MyAppFilter) is in the same package with the endpoints class.

My question is, how to make this filter usable across multiple packages. For instance, I create two OSGI bundles with package A and package B. Instead of creating filter for each bundle. I want to create a filter in one bundle/package and use it in another bundle.

**Package A:** I create the filter class MyAppFilter.java

**Package B:** I create the web.xml to consume the filter

```
<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>packageA.MyAppFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

I've tried this scenario, but it does not work for me.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Your Jersey 1.x filter will not work with Jersey 2.x. That `ServletContainer` you have for the servlet-class is 2.x. Jersey 2.x also has a `ContainerRexxxFilter`. But the package is different. And secondly the init-param you are using is also for 1.x which will have no affect on 2.x

Comment: @peeskillet sorry for the mixed between 1.x and 2.x. Its my typo. I edit the question to explain my situation better.

Comment: Are you asking how to make it work with different projects (wars). I don't quite get the whole question about different packages. Why do we need to use different packages for the filter? Maybe you might need to explain _"make this filter works across various package"_ a little better. It's not very clear what that means

Comment: @peeskillet thanks for the suggestion, They are OSGI bundles.

Comment: Why don't you just create a library of reusable components and include it in each bundle.